# Instanceof Double Java

Tags: java

I'm having some trouble using the instanceof Double, I'm getting errors regardless of if I use Double or double and if I do the parsing above or below the if statements.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: Errors differ depending on where the parse is, ranging from can't compare string to double which is obvious. But also can't compare double and Double, and invalid dimensions for double

```
List<String> graphlist = Arrays.asList(formula.split(","));

        if(!(graphlist.get(0) instanceof String || graphlist.get(1) instanceof String)){
        if(!(graphlist.get(2) instanceof Double|| graphlist.get(3) instanceof Double)){
                s.append("Invalid Graph Syntax.");
            }
        }
        lower = Double.parseDouble(graphlist.get(2));
        upper = Double.parseDouble(graphlist.get(3));
```

Comment: please include the errors

Comment: why don't you put it around a try catch block and get us the Exception

Comment: To you understand how typed container works? I would suggest you read a little about them before asking more questions that are so trivial : [Great FAQ about generics](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) and [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

Answer (score 4):

Your `graphList` will only ever contain `String` as it's a typed `List`. That's why it's giving you errors.

Why are you trying to get `Double`s from it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The List contains Strings, Strings are never instances of Double. What you want to know is whether the String may represent a Double I assume? If so, you could use the [Double#parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) function:

```
private boolean isDouble(String arg) {
    try {
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(arg);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you just put everything in a try-catch-block:

```
List<String> graphlist = Arrays.asList(formula.split(","));

if(!(graphlist.get(0) instanceof String || graphlist.get(1) instanceof String)){
    try {
        lower = Double.parseDouble(graphlist.get(2));
        upper = Double.parseDouble(graphlist.get(3));
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e) {
        s.append("Invalid Graph Syntax.");
    }
}
```